# To add dates to empty dataframe that are generated by Posixct function

Tags: r, posixct

I have created a sequence of dates with this script:

```
dates<-seq(
  from=as.POSIXct("2015-1-1 0","%Y-%m-%d %H", tz="UTC"),
  to=as.POSIXct("2015-12-31 24", "%Y-%m-%d %H", tz="UTC"),
  by="hour"
)
```

Now I want to store the result to the first column of empty dataframe:

```
df<-data.frame(Date=as.POSIXct(character()),Area=character(), Application=character(),  Type= character(),
               Reading=double())
```

using this code

```
df$Date<-dates
```

but it gives me error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "Date", value = c(1420070400, 1420074000,  : 
  replacement has 8761 rows, data has 0
```

Can anyone help me to sort out this issue please?

Comment: you try to allocate to one column of your dataframe a vector of 8761 elements whereas the other have zeros. So `R`"shouts". Rather try directly: `df<-data.frame(Date=dates,Area='', Application='',  Type= '',
               Reading=as.numeric(0))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `data.frame` needs columns of equal length and cannot have one column containing 8761 observations, and the rest 0. A workaround is to initialize a `data.frame` with the correct dimensions for your data, filled by `NA`; and then assign columns.

```
# Initialize df
df <- data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = length(dates), ncol = 5)) 
# Define names of cols and add column
names(df) <- c("Date", "Area", "Application", "Type", "Reading")
df$Date <- dates
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I realize the problem.